# Вопрос про позиционирование

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Верстаю макет. Для блоков header и section задал общий div, чтобы установить общий фон. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<body>
<div class="main-wrapper">
    <header class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navtop">
      <a href="#" class="logo"
        ><img src="img/logo.svg" alt="icon: logo" class="logo__image"
      /></a>
      <ul class="navtop-menu">
        <li class="navtop-menu__item">
          <a href="#" class="navtop-menu__link--active">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="navtop-menu__item">
          <a href="#" class="navtop-menu__link">Features</a>
        </li>
        <li class="navtop-menu__item">
          <a href="#" class="navtop-menu__link">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li class="navtop-menu__item">
          <a href="#" class="navtop-menu__link">Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li class="navtop-menu__item">
          <a href="#" class="navtop-menu__link">FAQ</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="navtop-buttons">
        <button class="navtop-buttons__signin">Sign In</button>
        <button class="navtop-buttons__getstarted">Get Started</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navtop -->
  </div>
</header>
<!-- /.header -->
<section class="hero">
  <div class="container">
    <p>в работе</p>
  </div>

</section>
<!-- /.hero -->
</div>
```

и css:
.main
&-wrapper
background: url('../img/bg-blue.svg') no-repeat fixed, url('../img/bg-grey.svg') 100% 780px no-repeat
height: 840px
ну и...
header
position: relative
top: 20px

Правильно ли так позиционировать header? И как теперь отодвинуть следующую секцию? Как правильно верстать  макеты, где фоновый рисунок на 2 секции?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Извиняюсь, не всю секцию выложил. Там именно рисунок на фоне...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Допустим HEADER у вас высотой 100px. Конкретно для этой страницы HEADER-у можно задать "z-index: 1; position: relative; margin-bottom: -100px" и он целиком провалится в нижнюю секцию с уникальным фоном. На остальных безфоновых страницах HEADER просто будет 100px.

Answer (score 1):

Зачем усложнять жизнь? Зачем фоновый рисунок на две секции?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
  padding: .5em 1em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 100%;
}

section {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #05f 70%, transparent 70%);
  padding-top: 3em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <span>Logo</span>
  <nav>
    <span>Link</span>
    <span>Link</span>
    <span>Link</span>
    <span>Link</span>
    <span>Link</span>
  </nav>
</header>
<section>
  <h1>Hello world</h1>
</section>
```